# Google App engine JSP form

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to use datastore in my program .That on one jsp i enter user info and after submitting it redirects me to another jsp where i can see all previous users information. Using datastore how to doit.

Answer (score 1):

Will this do it?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-java

There are plenty of other examples under the https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/

Also, you could see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore